# apache NiFi convert JSON to avro

Tags: json, twitter, apache-nifi, avro

How can I convert JSON to Avro in apache NiFi?

I.e. JSON is obtained using the `getTwitter`?
[image]

Previous versions seem to support a `ConvertJSONToAvro`.
To me, it looks like nowadays the convertRecord processor should be used:
[image]

I.e. using record-oriented processing to read the JSON using a JSON tree reader and write it to Avro.
But where / how do I specify the schema? Especially for such a complex schema as i.e. obtained from Twitter. Is NiFi automatically guessing the right schema somehow?

### edit

In fact, something rather obvious happens:

```
 ConvertRecord Failed to process StandardFlowFileRecord will route to failure: ${schema.name} did not provide appropriate Schema Name
```

I.e. convert record succeeds in parsing the json, but when trying to apply the avro writer it fails. So how could I get an avro representation from the tweets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to infer the schema and have that translated automatically to Avro using the modern record processors. [Abdelkrim Hadjidj has a great write up](https://medium.com/@abdelkrim.hadjidj/democratizing-nifi-record-processors-with-automatic-schemas-inference-4f2b2794c427) about it, but to summarize:

#### Modern method

Use the *Schema Inference* capability in the `JsonPathReader` or `JsonTreeReader` implementation you're using in `ConvertRecord`. This will allow it to infer the schema, and then pass that along to the `AvroRecordSetWriter` via the `schema.name` and `avro.schema` attributes. There is also a schema inference cache (use the provided volatile implementation unless you have other requirements) to improve performance.

#### Old method

Use the [`InferAvroSchema`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kite-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.kite.InferAvroSchema/index.html) processor to parse the incoming data and generate an Avro schema.

Note: **this processor is no longer included with default builds of NiFi due to space restrictions**, but you can manually build the `nifi-kite-nar` and then deploy it into the `$NIFI_HOME/extensions/` directory to load that functionality.

Comment: Well this is what I have written above. 1. I trued to use JSON Tree Reader in the convertRecordProcessor with the mode InferSchema (and presumably this works well). However, I also use the WriteAvroRecord as the scond step. The configuration of my writer: https://imgur.com/55lYdkk I tried to use allof (inherit, schema.name, schema.text) but somehow I cannot access the inferred schema - and thus fail. So could you share the settings of both please. Using schema.name requires the registry, and somehow the inferred schema does not seem to be published there.

Comment: Using:  the "inherit" schema access strategy works. But: it fails if fields like events, media, ... are contained media  field and lead to Can't redefine: org.apache.nifi.mediaType as the default generated/inferred avro schema seems to overlap. I am unsure how to best handle this.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler any updates on this ? What did work for you at the end?

Comment: Please check the github repository. There you find working code https://github.com/geoHeil/streaming-reference